# WCF - 'System.IO.Compression.GZipStream' cannot be serialized

Tags: c#, json, wcf, azure, gzip

I am using a WCF cloud service (Azure) to accept a compressed (GZIP) JSON POST request.

**My class**

```
[DataContract]
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class Omni : IOmnivore
{
    public async Task<System.Net.HttpStatusCode> GetOmnisJson(GZipStream inputJsonStream)
   {
        JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();

        using (var decompressor = new GZipStream(inputJsonStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(decompressor))
        using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            JObject jsonObj = (JObject)ser.Deserialize(jsonTextReader);

            // extract necessary info
            string dataType = (string)jsonObj["data_type"];
            string dataTypeEvent = (string)jsonObj["event"];
```

**My interface**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IOmnivore
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/PostOmnis",
        Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Task<System.Net.HttpStatusCode> GetOmnisJson(GZipStream json);
```

**My web.config (HTTP compression part)**

Not sure this is really needed in the web.config. This is WCF hosted on Azure, not sure about the **dll** part under `<httpCompression><scheme dll>` part..:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpCompression>
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" />
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
```

Having an argument of `GZipStream` type (since the input JSON is GZIPPed) gives a runtime error:

> 'System.IO.Compression.GZipStream' cannot be serialized. Consider
>   marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute.

My class is already marked as a `[DataContract]` but I see no different outcome.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to do GZip yourself. IIS will do it for you - you just need to enable Dynamic Content Compression in your web.config.

Comment: I updated my question to show how I did this.. still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because the `GZipStream` class is not marked as `Serializable` or with a `DataContractAttribute`.

Unless you have access to & can modify the source of the `GZipStream` class, you will not be able to pass any instance of the `GZipStream` class to a WCF `ServiceContract`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't paste the complete class definition. I've edited my question to show that it already includes both a Serializable and a DataContract attributes. Still crashes.

Comment: The Omni class is correct, the issue is with the GZipStream class being used as a parameter for the GetOmnisJson method.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not mean that it can be Serialized. The GZipStream class itself does not have any of the required attributes to allow WCF to serialize it. If you were to pass the base class, Stream, it would be serialized but not GZipStream.

Comment: I tried that as well but crashes on line: JObject jsonObj = (JObject)ser.Deserialize(jsonTextReader); You can see my other Q about that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749637/gzipstream-decompress-of-stream-fails

Comment: As @matthensley-io pointed, GZipStream is not an object that can be serialized. You can use it to compress the data and return a byte array or, if your goal is to reduce message size, you can let `IIS` compress to you. Read more here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCFDataFeedsODataAndOtherCustomServicesInIIS7.aspx